# How to compare the current URL?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, mstest

I want to assert the URLof the page after login. This is my method so far:

```
public bool UrlEqualsBookingPage()
{
    string currentURL = Client.GetCurrentUrl();
    string expectedURL = "https://url.at";

    return String.Equals(currentURL, expectedURL);
}
```

This is my test method:

```
[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("Podmanager")]
public void DF_Podmanager_Login_UrlCheck()
{ 
    // ARRANGE - user generated by dataprovider
    User user = UserDataProvider.UserPodManager();

    // ACT - check url
    var result = dfApp.Web().Login(user).UrlEqualsBookingPage();

    // ASSERT - url is as expected
    result.Should().BeTrue();
}
```

I'm not sure, how to get the current URL compared to the one in the ().
What do I miss?

Test fails with 'false' if I run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to make it work, here is the functioning method:

```
public bool AssertBookingPageURL()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        string currentURL = Client.GetCurrentUrl();
       
        string expectedURL = "https://www.url.at";

        return currentURL.Equals(expectedURL);
    }
```

Test Method:

```
    [TestMethod]
    [TestCategory("Podmanager")]
    public void DF_Podmanager_Login_UrlCheck()
    {
        // ARRANGE - user generated by dataprovider
        User user = UserDataProvider.UserPodManager();

        // ACT - check url
        var result = dfApp.Web().Login(user).AssertBookingPageURL();

        // ASSERT - url is as expected
        result.Should().BeTrue();
    }
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you current URL

```
WebDriver driver = new WebDriver();
String currentURL =  driver.getCurrentURL();
String expectedURL = "https://expectedURL.com";
```

Now you can compare the URL

```
if (String.Equals(currentURL, expectedURL))
    Console.WriteLine ($"{currentURL} and {expectedURL} have the same value.");
```

Comment: Hi Ruppal, thank you so much for your answer! I still can't make it work unfortunately. I'm adding my test method, maybe this makes it more clear.

Comment: I changed the code like this, to make it work; but the test result is false, i dont understand why, do you? public bool UrlEqualsBookingPage()
        {
            string currentURL = Client.GetCurrentUrl();
            string expectedURL = "https://url.at";

            return String.Equals(currentURL, expectedURL);
           
        }

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a race condition between the web page loading in the browser and the execution of your C# test. An explicit wait is required here to mitigate this:

```
public bool UrlEqualsBookingPage(int secondsToWait = 30)
{
    const string expectedURL = "https://url.at";
    var wait = new WebDriverWait(Client, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secondsToWait));

    try
    {
        return wait.Until(driver => expectedURL.Equals(driver.GetCurrentUrl(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }
    catch (WebDriverTimeoutException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

A couple of notes:

- URLs are not case sensitive, so make sure you do a case **in**sensitive comparison.
- Explicit waits throw exceptions if the condition isn't met within a certain amount of time. In this case, consider renaming your method to `void AssertUrlIsBookingPage(...)` and let the WebDriverWait object throw an exception. Then your test becomes simply:

  ```
  User user = UserDataProvider.UserPodManager();

  dfApp.Web().Login(user).AssertUrlIsBookingPage();
  ```